# Finding ListView item from row index in Javascript

Tags: javascript, listview

If I know the DisplayIndex of the ListView item I want to find, how can I find it in javascript?

As a reference, here is how I can do it if I know the index of the item in a GridView:

```
//  get the gridview element
var gridView = $get('<%= this.GridView1.ClientID %>');
//Get the selected row
var curSelRow = gridView.rows[parseInt(rowIdx)+1];
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in the end.  It looks like you are trying to assign a GridViewRow object to a javascript variable which seems odd to me...  Do you just want the values out of the row?

Comment: @Abe I am trying to render a Loading div over the item when the user clicks on the Select button for that item.  See Matt Berseth's version on doing this for any control: http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/06/aspnet_ajax_rendering_a_gmaill.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot.  I haven't had a chance to test it yet, but I'll post back once I do.

```
var targetItem = $get('<%= lv_MyLv.Items[lv_MyLv.SelectedIndex].ClientID%>');
```

Comment: Can you please explain this ::                                                                       var targetItem = $get('<%= lv_MyLv.Items[lv_MyLv.SelectedIndex].ClientID%>');